# Unicode error from already decoded string?

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-requests

I am having an issue joining a string that I have already decoded earlier in my code:

```
import json
import requests
import jsonobject

for i in range(0, 3): #for loop to feed parameter to url params

    if i == 0:
        var = "0"
        var2 = "Home"
    elif i == 1:
        var = "1"
        var2 = "Away"
    elif i == 2:
        var = "2"
        var2 = "Overall"

    url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics'
    params = {
            'category': 'tackles',
            'subcategory': 'success',
            'statsAccumulationType': '0',
            'isCurrent': 'true',
            'playerId': '',
            'teamIds': '',
            'matchId': '',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'tournamentOptions': '2',
            'sortBy': 'Rating',
            'sortAscending': '',
            'age': '',
            'ageComparisonType': '',
            'appearances': '',
            'appearancesComparisonType': '0',
            'field': var2, #from for loop
            'nationality': '',
            'positionOptions': "'FW','AML','AMC','AMR','ML','MC','MR','DMC','DL','DC','DR','GK','Sub'",
            'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
            'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
            'isMinApp': '',
            'page': '1',
            'includeZeroValues': '',
            'numberOfPlayersToPick': '10'
            }

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

        responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
        responser = responser.json()
        playerTableStats = responser[u'playerTableStats']

    for statDict in playerTableStats:

        mylookup = ("{name},{firstName},{lastName},{positionText},{tournamentId},{tournamentShortName},{regionCode}"
            "{tournamentRegionId},{seasonId},{seasonName},{teamName},{teamId},{playerId}"
            "{minsPlayed},{ranking},{rating:.2f},{apps},{weight:.2f},{height:.2f},{playedPositions}"
            "{isManOfTheMatch},{isOpta},{subOn},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict)) #generates none match data about players
        print mylookup


        mykey2 = (var2)
        print mykey2

        mykey3 = {}
        #create dynamic variables and join match and none match data together
        mykey3[mykey2] = ("{challengeLost:.2f},{tackleWonTotal:.2f},{tackleTotalAttempted:.2f},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))
        print mykey3[mykey2]
        mykey3[mykey2] = mykey3[mykey2],'*,'
        mykey3[mykey2] = str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2]))
        mykey3[mykey2] = mylookup,mykey3[mykey2]
        mykey3[mykey2] = str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2]))
        print mykey3[mykey2]

        mykey3[mykey2] = mykey3[mykey2],'*,'
        mykey3[mykey2] = str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2]))
```

I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\counter.py", line 72, in <module>
    mykey3[mykey2] = str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2]))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when the name `Cesc Fàbregas` is encountered in the list of player names being cycled though. I have tried amending the above code to:

```
mykey3[mykey2] = mykey3[mykey2],'*,'
mykey3[mykey2] = str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2]).decode('cp1252'))
```

...or:

```
mykey3[mykey2] = mykey3[mykey2],'*,'
mykey3[mykey2] = str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2])).decode('cp1252')
```

...however this is still generating the same error....

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than decoding string literals, just use `u'...'` and use a [PEP-263 source code declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) if any strings are not just ASCII.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have corrected the indentation now. with regards to your suggestion, this is an area i am unfamiliar with...is there not a way to code it placing .decode somewhere in the string join statement to make the code work?

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you actually pulling out the *name*. You appear to only be putting in a comma-separated list of stats (floating point numbers).

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you run the above code it prints a series of strings to the log...when it encounters the one that says cesc fabregas it throws up an error because of the none ascii characters in the name

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `str()` on the 2-value tuple you created. Why not just format your stats to just include the `*,` at the end: `u"{challengeLost:.2f},{tackleWonTotal:.2f},{tackleTotalAttempted:.2f},*,".format(**statDict)`?

Comment: Yet I cannot reproduce your issue with the code posted here.

Comment: well that would work for briging in the '*', but for reasons that i cant really explain without printing my full code (which is huge) i still need to a join a string that contains players names with one that contains game stats, which is what is causing the error

Comment: @MartijnPieters im running my code on windows in python shell...what environment are you using?

Comment: Ah, no, I see where that is now.

Comment: it is in the variable 'mylookup'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to join two values with a comma in a *very roundabout way*, by creating a tuple then turning the tuple back into a string. Don't do that, just use string formatting.

You need to use *Unicode literals* rather than decode your strings:

```
mykey3[mykey2] = u"{challengeLost:.2f},{tackleWonTotal:.2f},{tackleTotalAttempted:.2f},".format(**statDict)
```

Note the `u` prefix on the string. You are not actually using any non-ASCII characters in your string literals, so you don't even need to declare an encoding there.

But your use of tuples then using `str()` on those is causing your exceptions. Just don't use `str()` here at all; you are trying to convert Unicode strings joined together into a byte string again, after which you are trying to join that byte string back with a Unicode value, and convert to a byte string *again*, which failed:

```
>>> mylookup = ("{name},{firstName},{lastName},{positionText},{tournamentId},{tournamentShortName},{regionCode}"
...             "{tournamentRegionId},{seasonId},{seasonName},{teamName},{teamId},{playerId}"
...             "{minsPlayed},{ranking},{rating:.2f},{apps},{weight:.2f},{height:.2f},{playedPositions}"
...             "{isManOfTheMatch},{isOpta},{subOn},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))
>>> ''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2])
u'Cesc F\xe0bregas,Cesc,F\xe0bregas,Midfielder,2,EPL,es252,4311,2014/2015,Chelsea,15,8040532,5,8.09,6,74.00,175.00,-FW-MC-ML-MR-False,True,0,2.83,1.17,4.00,*,*,2.83,1.17,4.00,*,'
>>> str(''.join(mykey3[mykey2][0:2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note that the join happened to work; it was the `str()` call that converts the Unicode back to a byte string without an explicit codec.

The following also joins two (Unicode) strings with a comma:

```
mykey3[mykey2] = u','.join(mykey3[mykey2], u'*,')
```

or just append to the existing string:

```
mykey3[mykey2] += u',*,'
```

or just use **one** string formatting operation to put all your data into one string to begin with:

```
mylookup = (
    u"{name},{firstName},{lastName},{positionText},{tournamentId},{tournamentShortName},{regionCode}"
    u"{tournamentRegionId},{seasonId},{seasonName},{teamName},{teamId},{playerId}"
    u"{minsPlayed},{ranking},{rating:.2f},{apps},{weight:.2f},{height:.2f},{playedPositions}"
    u"{isManOfTheMatch},{isOpta},{subOn},"
    u"{challengeLost:.2f},{tackleWonTotal:.2f},{tackleTotalAttempted:.2f},"
    u"*,*,".format(**statDict)
)
```